# CTRL-click behavior in wx.ListBox with multiple selections

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx.ListBox that I would like the user to select from as if they were holding down the CTRL key.  So - if you click on an item that is not selected, it will be selected (without modifying other selections), and if you click on a selected item, it will be deselected (again without modifying other selections).

The code to create the listbox is:

```
    self.myListBox = wx.ListBox(self,
                                    -1,
                                    choices=self.keys,
                                    style =  wx.LB_HSCROLL
                                           | wx.LB_MULTIPLE
                                           | wx.LB_NEEDED_SB
                                           | wx.LB_SORT)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnSelection, self.myListBox)
```

Problems / questions:

- Is there already an easy way to do this?  Either `wx.LB_MULTIPLE` or `wx.LB_EXTENDED` look like they might be what I want, but I've tried both and it doesn't appear to change anything.  The description in the documentation is a little vague as well - what exactly is the difference between the two?
- I know can get the id of the selected item with `event.GetSelection()`, but if I try to implement the above logic, i.e.:

  ```
  if self.myListBox.IsSelected(idx):
      self.myListBox.Deselect(idx)
  else:
      self.myListBox.Select(idx)
  ```

  the event has already fired and so it just deselects whatever was just selected.  Tried calling `event.Skip()` before that as well, but no luck there either.  Is there a way I can stop it from doing that?
- I noticed that when dragging the mouse for multiple selections `event.GetSelection()` would get the correct id's going up - i.e., `3, 2, 1, 0` - but going down it would only show the first - `0, 0, 0, 0`.  I'm guessing it's just printing out the first item in the list of selections -- is there a way to get the list from the event object (as opposed to calling `self.myListBox.GetSelections()`)?

I'm running Linux and wxPython version 2.6.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Late answer, but it might be of use to document.)
I ended up writing handlers for the onClick events:

```
def OnSelection(self, event):
    """Simulate CTRL-click"""
    selection = self.myListBox.GetSelections()

    for i in selection:
        if i not in self.selectedItems:
            # add to list of selected items
            self.selectedItems.append(i)
            self.myListBox.Select(i)
        elif len(selection) == 1:
            # remove from list of selected items
            self.selectedItems.remove(i)
            self.myListBox.Deselect(i)

    for i in self.selectedItems:
        # actually select all the items in the list
        self.myListBox.Select(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

wxPython 2.6.x is super old. Upgrade to the 2.8 or 2.9 series. I just ran the wxPython demo for 2.8.11 and it seemed to work fine for me on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's old, but upgrading is not an option for this project at the moment.  Also - could you define what "works fine" means?  Has the requested behavior in 2.8.11?

Comment: I can CTRL+click to toggle the selection

Comment: Yes, that works for me too.  Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear -- what I want to do is simulate that behavior _without_ the user actually pressing the CTRL key.

Comment: You would probably need to create a custom control then. I don't think the native control supports that feature.